# Web3 Library Javascript - getAccounts vs accounts.wallet[0]

Tags: javascript, web3js

I have the following code:

```
const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);

console.log('Accounts:', await web3.eth.getAccounts()); 

console.log('Wallet Account:', web3.eth.accounts.wallet[0]);
```

This returns me 2 different things. The first one, returns me "Accounts: 0xEF..42a3", which is my wallet address, while the other one returns me "undefined"

Why are these two ways so different if they apply to the same area?

Comment: Have you resolved this issue yet? If so, did my answer below help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation for `web3.eth.getAccounts()`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.8.0/web3-eth.html#getaccounts) reads as follows:

> Returns a list of accounts the node controls.
>
> ###### Returns:
>
> `Promise` returns `Array` - An array of addresses controlled by node.

While the [documentation for `web3.eth.accounts`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.8.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#eth-accounts) reads as follows:

> The `web3.eth.accounts` [object] contains functions to generate Ethereum accounts and sign transactions and data.

**So, they do not refer to the same thing, and `web.eth.getAccounts()` is what you are looking for**. `web3.eth.getAccounts()` returns an array of accounts, but `web.eth.accounts` is an object full of functions do general operations.

You might have been confused that `web.eth.accounts.wallet[0]` returns `undefined` instead of an error. This is just a weird JS thing. In JS, arrays are actually objects with numerical keys. So, `wallet[0]` actually means "get the value for the key `0` from the object `wallet`". Because `wallet` is an object, no error is returned. However, `wallet` has no key `0`, so `undefined` is returned.